# Laravel: Registration and Login using Passport Oauth Token (ReflectionException: Controller does not exist)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

So I'm trying to use the Laravel Api Passport and I'm getting this error.

**ReflectionException:**

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController does not exist
```

Whenever I try to enter this command: "php artisan route:list"

My route codes are placed in my **api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});
Route::post('/register','Api\AuthController@register');
```

I guess the error is located in **api.php** but I dont know where is it.

Here's the **AuthController.php** codes

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
   public function register(Request $request){
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'email'=>'required',
        'name'=>'required',
        'password'=>'required'
    ]);

    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();

    $http = new Client;

    $response = $http->post(url('oauth/token'), [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => '2',
            'client_secret' => 'C0aJVstKoiTxx1HrCQEwBOYNKYHhMCGN9w6NUz57',
            'username' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'scope' => '',
        ],
    ]);

    return response(['data'=>json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)]);
}
public function login(){

}
}
```

I'm following this tutorial on youtube : *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiVA2Oko23o*

It's my part two already I did everything explained in the tutorial but seems like there's something wrong with my codes I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so newbie I found that the problem is located in **api.php**

**Auth** should be place before **Api**

```
Route::post('/register','Auth\Api\AuthController@register');
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forget to put '\'.
you should try this.

```
Route::post('/register','\Api\AuthController@register');
```

Laravel route always locates the controller class on `\Controller` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the action by

```
http://{your_domain}/api/register
```